# how can I bind ID property to checkbox in xaml WUP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

First thank you guys in StackOverFlow to give the opportunity, u guys doin really great job, I'm very beginner in windows 10 universal apps, I created app which has employee class for example in the models folder let us say like the following:

```
 public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

and in xaml I created  AutoSuggestBox and listView which I bind to ObervableCollection list of type Employee and this as the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind EmployeesList}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Employee">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Checked="StatusCB_Checked"
                              Margin="5,2,5,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="EmpNametxtBlk"
                                   Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Now once I type name in the AutoSuggestBox the list view will show the checkBox and the employee name , I want to check the checkbox and I want to get the employee object to get deleted from the list view and then add to another list view let's say for chosen employees , my questions is how I can bind the checkBox to the employee ID and then i can use that object in the code behind for the check event ? I mean once i check the checkbox of any added employee on the Listview I wanted to do :
deleted that employee from the ListView and add him in other list view 
the other list view will be hidden till I delete employees from the first Listview.
how I can bind the checkbox to the ID of the employee and how I can extract the employee object in the check event or any other even, well I wish I explained what I want in clear way !

Comment: You can't bind the checkbox to the employee ID you can only bind data to properties

Answer (score 0):

`how I can extract the employee object in the check event or any other even`

You can get the object from `DataContext` property of the `sender` object (just make sure you cast the `sender` from `object` to `FrameworkElement` type first)

Comment: can please elaborate bit ?  which property of the checkbox I can bind the object ID with ?

Comment: you can bind to Tag property

Answer (score 0):

As @thang2410199 said

> You can get the object from `DataContext` property of the `sender` object.

You don't need bind the Id property to somewhere for deleting since you can get the employee instance from checkbox's [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) property. You can delete the checked employee using the following code:

```
 private void StatusCB_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
     if(checkbox!=null)
     {
         var employee =(Employee)checkbox.DataContext;
         Employeeslist.Remove(employee);
     }           
 }
```

A completed demo to meet your requirements you can download [here](https://github.com/sunteenwu/PersonalDemo). More details about Listview reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView).

Answer (score 0):

1. For your list you should use an ObservableCollection.
2. Implement the    INotifyPropertyChanged Interface so the UI is getting notified when data is changing.
3. Create a new class called ListCountToVisibilityConverter.cs, Implement the IValueConverter interface. When the count of your
   Observable collection is > 0  return Visibility.Visible else return
   Visibility.Collapsed .
4. You can delete Items by getting the selected index in the ListView and you can add items by using the add method of the observable collection.
5. You may want to implement the MVVM pattern. [MVVM Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)